# Selenium controlled browser not working properly?

Tags: selenium, automation

I am trying to automate a website, and there is a dynamic drop-down which pops up based on the text entered. This drop-down works fine on any normal browser.

But when I execute the selenium test, the drop-down never shows up.  I even stopped the execution of the test but did not close the browser that opened by selenium. I refreshed the website, tried to manually entered the text, and still the dropdown was not showing up.

Comment: Show your attempted code so far.

Comment: also check the browser console for errors

Comment: try using a firefox profile wile launching selenium

Comment: Is you site genearate dropdown list fields using KendoUI or AngularJS ? those are dynamically created lists or divs, So, I think your sendkeys function not filling values but it seems to be fiiled but actually not getting binded with the UI DOM So, the next dropdown not getting populated. Please share you code for more clarification of exact problem.